# Get height of dynamically changing element

Tags: javascript, jquery

This piece of code gets the height of `.divone` (which is responsive) and adds it as margin-top to `.divtwo`:

```
    var height = $(".divone").height();
    $('.divtwo').css({"margin-top": height + "px"});
```

How can I achieve that `height` gets updated, anytime the browser window gets resized and the height of `.divone` changes?

I added this line, but I it didn't work at all:

```
 $(window).on("resize", height)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `.on(String event, Function handler)` takes a minimum of two arguments: the `event` you want to listen to as a string, then a `function` to execute when the event triggers.

```
function recalcDivTwo() {
  var height = $('.divone').height();
  $('.divtwo').css({"margin-top": height + "px"});
}
```

Then add this to your document.ready handler:

```
$(window).on("resize", recalcDivTwo);
```

You can also define the handler function as an anonymous function in the call:

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  $('.divtwo').css({"margin-top": $('.divone').height() + "px"});
});
```

On short handler functions that serve no other purpose than that specific event handling I'd go with an anonymous, inline function definition as it also does not pollute the global namespace.

> https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You're welcome. Take your time to read the jQuery documentation on stuff that you're about to use. It's really well-documented.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).resize(func);
Var func=function(){
var height = $(".divone").height();
    $('.divtwo').css({"margin-top": height + "px"});
}
```